# PHP fopen() Permission denied

Tags: php, apache, centos

I'm a PHP learner and I'm working with files but I can't open a file in my own server because there is a "permission denied" error. I'm using `fopen()` function: `fopen('file.txt', 'r+');`

I'm using Apache 2.4.37 and PHP 7.2.11 in a CentOS. I've been searching a lot in the internet but nothing worked, I had installed fpm, I tried with other PHP version, I check that `allow_url_fopen` is turned on,  I reinstalled PHP and Apache, I ensured all permissions are OK. I also install in a VM other CentOS but the problem was on it too, then I tried with Ubuntu and it worked perfectly but my server is running in CentOS.

Comment: Are you running it from a web page? The webserver userid needs to have read permission. That username is usually something like www-user or www-data.

Comment: What kind of path are you using ? Relative  (ie: `../folder/myimage.jpg`) or absolute (ie: `http://www.mywebsite.com/folder/myimage.jpg`) ?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the code from a web page but the entire folder are own by web server username and group in CentOS is httpd and permissions for all files are set in 777.

Comment: I'm using a relative path because the txt file is on the same folder than php code. However, using an absolute path like '/var/www/html/file.txt' doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried file_get_contents instead to see if that works? If you use unlink('file.txt'); does the file get deleted? If not, your permissions are certainly not correct.

Comment: The user that runs your apache must have proper rights to access the file.  If that is fine, look at the settings in httpd.conf regarding `<Directory ...>`.  This controls how Apache itself is allowed to handle directories relative to user requests.

Comment: Hey! have you tried to assign the file to the user:group "apache:apache" i think that will help instead of httpd, so $sudo chown apache:apache file.txt maybe i'm wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have searching all the day but finally I resolved it. The problem was about SELinux.

I don't know why but SELinux comes in enforcing mode by default but when I turned it off all was solved. If you don't want to turn it off because security reasons you can set permissions but it's kind advanced for beginners users to understand. I found how to set these permissions here:  https://serverfault.com/a/819370

If you don't want to fight against SELinux you can turn it off by editing `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` and put `permissive` (recommended) or `disabled` after `SELINUX=`

If you want to learn more about SELinux, DigitalOcean has an excellent posts about that: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorial_series/an-introduction-to-selinux-on-centos-7

Comment: Turning off the best thing CentOS has to offer is the worst thing you can do. Instead you should configure it properly.

Comment: @emix SELinux is for sysadmins or for advanced linux users. If you want to keep it turned on I gave a link to settings and more information about it, I think if someone come to this post searching help they probably don't know about SELinux and don't need it.